# Progressbar in ListBox Background?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, progress-bar

I have the following Listbox:

```
    <ListBox Margin="5" Grid.Column="0" Name="ListboxSelectUpdate">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>

                <ProgressBar Visibility="Visible">
                    <ProgressBar.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Progress}" Value="0">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"></Setter>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ProgressBar.Style>
                    <ProgressBar.Template>
                        <ControlTemplate>
                            <AdornedElementPlaceholder Name="adorner">
                                <Grid>
                                    <TextBlock Width="70" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold">Version:</TextBlock>
                                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Version}"></TextBlock>
                                </Grid>
                            </AdornedElementPlaceholder>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </ProgressBar.Template>
                </ProgressBar>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

In this Listbox I want to show different available Updates / Versions for a program.
Now I want to have a Progressbar in the Background of the ItemTemplate, which is only visible if the Progess-Property (int) is not zero. (so if the Update starts, the Progress-Property isnt zero and the Progressbar should be visible).
My Problem: I cant see anything, no Progressbar and no TexbBlocks.
Where is my misstake?

Answer (score 0):

Your template is a bit wrong. You have misused `AdornedElementPlaceholder` element which, according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.adornedelementplaceholder.aspx) should be used only for validation templates. And you don't put things inside `AdornedElementPlaceholder`, it's a place where decorated control is put. If you want to stack controls on top of each other then use `Grid`. Try this `ListBox` template instead:

```
<ListBox Margin="5" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=MyList}">
  <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
          <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
      </Style>
  </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
  <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
          <Grid>
              <ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="{Binding Progress, Mode=OneWay}">
                  <ProgressBar.Style>
                      <Style TargetType="{x:Type ProgressBar}">
                          <Style.Triggers>
                              <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Progress}" Value="0">
                                  <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                              </DataTrigger>
                          </Style.Triggers>
                      </Style>
                  </ProgressBar.Style>
              </ProgressBar>
              <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <TextBlock Width="70" FontStyle="Italic" FontWeight="Bold">Version:</TextBlock>
                  <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Path=Version}"/>
              </StackPanel>
          </Grid>
      </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```